# Create extent reports with custom logs

Tags: selenium, extentreports

Need to print log4j logs in extent reports. HOw can I do that?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: @Anshoo any update on this?

Comment: Seems like your tests are being overwritten by each other, thus logs being shared. Can you use something like this to manage your tests:  https://github.com/anshooarora/extentreports-java/blob/master/src/test/java/com/aventstack/extentreports/common/ExtentTestManager.java

Comment: What do we want to achieve? How is it going to help? Could you provide some background? How it would make logs stick to its corresponding test only?

Comment: We want to ensure that in any given thread, only the correct test is used to log information. Since you have not shared the entire code, I have assumed that extentTest is being overwritten by multiple threads and/or classes accessing the BaseClass. We would like to avoid this scenario and send information only to the test belonging to the thread in a thread safe manner.

Comment: How do I use it? Should I declare in BaseTest as `public static ExtentReports extentReports = ExtentManager.getInstance();` like we used to in earlier versions of `extentReports`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to end the test and flush the report in  @AfterMethod and close the report in @AfterTest Method. It worked for me. Try it Like Below Code:

```
@AfterMethod(alwaysRun=true)
  public void TearDown_AM(ITestResult result) throws IOException
  {
      System.out.println("@After Method");
    try
    { 
        if(result.getStatus()==ITestResult.FAILURE)
        {
            String res = captureScreenshot(Driver, result.getName());
            String image= logger.addScreenCapture(res);
            System.out.println(image);
            String TestCaseName = this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " Test Case Failure and Title/Boolean Value Failed";
            logger.log(LogStatus.FAIL, TestCaseName  + logger.addScreenCapture(res));
            //  logger.log(LogStatus.FAIL, image, this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " Test Case Failure and Title/Boolean Value Failed");
        }
        else if(result.getStatus()==ITestResult.SUCCESS)
        {
            logger.log(LogStatus.PASS, this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " Test Case Success and Title Verified"); 
        }
        else if(result.getStatus()==ITestResult.SKIP)
        {
            logger.log(LogStatus.SKIP, this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " Test Case Skipped");
        }
        report.endTest(logger);
        report.flush();

    }
    catch(Throwable t)
    {
        logger.log(LogStatus.ERROR,t.fillInStackTrace());
    }

  }

@AfterTest(alwaysRun=true)
public void AfterTest()
{
    System.out.println("@After Test");
    Driver.close();
    report.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, create a class with a synchronized method which returns an instance of **`ExtentReports`**:

```
    public class ExtentManager {
    private static ExtentReports report;

    public static synchronized ExtentReports getInstance() {
        if (report == null) {
            report = new ExtentReports("MyReport.html");
        }

        return report;
    }
}
```

Secondly, create another class which declares only **test** related synchronized methods ( & of course, those method must be handled **Thread** wise). Code snippet:

```
public class ExtentTestManager {
    static Map<Integer, ExtentTest> extentTestMap = new HashMap<Integer, ExtentTest>();

    private static ExtentReports extent = ExtentManager.getInstance();

    public static synchronized ExtentTest getTest() {
        return extentTestMap.get((int) (long) (Thread.currentThread().getId()));
    }

    public static synchronized void endTest() {
        extent.endTest(extentTestMap.get((int) (long) (Thread.currentThread().getId())));
    }

    public static synchronized ExtentTest startTest(String testName) {
        return startTest(testName, "");
    }

    public static synchronized ExtentTest startTest(String testName, String desc) {
        ExtentTest test = extent.startTest(testName, desc);
        extentTestMap.put((int) (long) (Thread.currentThread().getId()), test);

        return test;
    }
}
```

Finally, modify your **BaseClass** accordingly:

```
public class BaseClass extends TestListenerAdapter {
    public ExtentTest testReporter;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod(Method m) {
        ExtentTestManager.startTest(m.getName(), "This is a simple test.");
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void afterMethod(ITestResult result) {
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(LogStatus.PASS, "Test passed");
            ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(LogStatus.PASS, "Run from thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        }
        else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
            ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Test failed");
            ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(LogStatus.PASS, "Run from thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        }
        else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP) {
            ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(LogStatus.SKIP, "Test skipped");
            ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(LogStatus.PASS, "Run from thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        }
        ExtentTestManager.endTest();
        ExtentManager.getInstance().flush();
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void afterSuite() {
        ExtentManager.getInstance().flush();
    }
}
```

**EDIT :**

Create a test class (`ExampleTest.java`) with your test:

```
public class ExampleTest extends BaseClass{
     @Test
        public void test_01(){
            Assert.assertTrue(false);
        }
        @Test
        public void test_02(){
            Assert.assertTrue(false);
        }
        @Test
        public void test_03(){
            Assert.assertTrue(true);
        }
        @Test
        public void test_04(){
            Assert.assertTrue(false);
        }
}
```

Required `testng.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="DemoSuite1" parallel="methods" thread-count="2">
    <test name = "Test">
        <classes>
            <class name = "com.extent.demo.ExampleTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: OK and how a testcase would start. Actually it is giving me null error.

Comment: Please, see the edited answer. Hope, it may help you.

Comment: To reproduce this issue, there should be two different `<class>` tags under `<classes>` tag in your `testng.xml` and thread count should be none. Also you didnt set reporter, your code asked me to start at least one reporter.

Comment: If you are using eclipse IDE and have TestNG plugin installed, you can run  the suite easily without any modification.

Comment: There is no problem in running it is just that whenever I have two classes under class tag and parallel parameter as methods, then it is appending report to last test. Sequentially it was always working fine for me.

Comment: Did you ever look at the generated report closely? To turn off the appending mode, change the report initialization in ExtentManager.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159499/discussion-between-optimist-creeper-and-paul).

Comment: The answer is working when test parallel?? I am looking solution for the same problem